# How to get all post status

Tags: php, post-type

I need to modify this code to show all post status, not just published. Any idea?

```
$post_types = get_post_types(array('public'=>true),'names');
    $post_type = !empty($_REQUEST['type']) && in_array($_REQUEST['type'], $post_types) ? $_REQUEST['type']:get_option('wpfc_default_type');
    $args['post_type'] = $post_type;
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish'; // need modifi here?
    $args['posts_per_page'] = -1;
    if( $args['post_type'] == 'attachment' ) $args['post_status'] = 'inherit';
    $args['tax_query'] = array();
    foreach( get_object_taxonomies($post_type) as $taxonomy_name ){
        if( !empty($_REQUEST[$taxonomy_name]) ){
            $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy_name,
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_REQUEST[$taxonomy_name]
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanx! Its working like charm!

Answer (score 0):

[As documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#status-parameters) you can set the `post_status` argument to `'any'` to retrive

> ...any status except those from post statuses with ‘exclude_from_search’ set to true (i.e. trash and auto-draft).

So:

```
$args['post_status'] = 'any';
```